# Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 70 - Nativescript

Tags: ios, nativescript, app-store-connect, nativescript-vue

I'm using Nativescript (using VScode) and trying to upload my app in App Store Connect following steps from official {N} [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-ios-apps#app-store-connect). When I'm done with all steps: set Bundle ID, edit Info.plist and build.xcconfig, create distribution certificate, app identifier, provisioning distribution profile. I run the following command in VS code:

`tns publish iOS *My_Apple_ID* *My_Apple_Password* *Provisioning_Profile_UUID* iPhone Distribution --appleApplicationSpecificPassword *password_for_two_factor_auth*`

and then I get this error:

> Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""nsvue.app" requires a
> provisioning profile." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3,
> NSLocalizedDescription="nsvue.app" requires a provisioning profile.,
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the
> "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property
> list.}
>
> ** EXPORT FAILED **
>
> Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 70

My question is:

#### What I'm doing wrong? How to make it work?

Here's in detail what I had done so far:

*Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles*

- Distribution certificate generated by Xcode
- Registered App Identifier (BundleID) is *"com.nativescript.nsvue"* (my app's name is *"nsvue"* and I had tried BundleId to be same as the app name, but without success same error again)
- Provisioning profile *(where the REAL problem is)* name of the provisioning profile with App ID - *"My_Development_Team.com.nativescript.nsvue"*.  Then I dowloaded it and installed it on my Mac.

*App Store Connect*

Create app with same BundleId as my app's and prepare it for submission now only I need to upload my app in App Store Connect

*Package.json, Info.plist and build.xcconfig*

Thats how my [Info.plist](https://github.com/stanimirsp5/Notes/blob/master/Info.plist) looks like. And that's [build.xcconfig](https://github.com/stanimirsp5/Notes/blob/master/build.xcconfig). Id of my app in [package.json](https://github.com/stanimirsp5/Notes/blob/master/package.json) is *"com.nativescript.nsvue"*  too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a related issue in the NativeScript GitHub Issues: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3222

While I'm not 100% sure *why* this problem exists, I have found that you can work around the problem by explicitly passing your provisioning profile uuid on the command line with the `--provision` flag, like this:

```
tns appstore upload *My_Apple_ID* *My_Apple_Password* --appleApplicationSpecificPassword *password_for_two_factor_auth* --provision *Provisioning_Profile_UUID*
```

Note: I *think* `tns publish` has been replaced with `tns appstore upload`...but under the covers, I think they're the same command...FWIW

Hope this helps as a work around for others that find this thread.